# FQL Testing Tool Vanished?

Tags: testing, facebook-fql

This is my first post here, so I should probably start by saying thankyou for the myriad of issues you have helped me to resolve.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

The fql.query page had a utility that allowed you to build FQL statements and test their results using one of your Applications access tokens. Is it just me or has it vanished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You now use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool for testing everything.

In the large dialog box, you type `fql?q=` followed by your query. e.g: `fql?q=SELECT username FROM user WHERE uid = me()`

There are other buttons that let you use a custom access token or one of your page's tokens methods.

Answer (score 1):

agrees with cpilko, use the Graph API Explorer.

You can bookmark this link instead, It auto switches the tab to FQL https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql